# nodes with 2 computers

Tags: ros, ros-master-uri, ros-hostname, multi-machine

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am trying to make a node on one computer(computer A) with some publishers and some services and try to read the messages and call some services with another computer(computer B).

computer A(ip is 192.168.1.100) and computer B(ip is 192.168.1.101) are connected since they can ping each other

computer A runs a roscore since it is the master.

on computer A, I set the ROS_MASTER_URI at http://localhost:11311
on computer B, I set the ROS_MASTER_URI at http://192.168.1.100:11311 and the ROS_HOSTNAME at 192.168.1.101

and yet it doesn't work, I don't even receive the topics messages,

I am sure I am doing something wrong or maybe didn't configure my network properly.

Does someone happen to know how to solve the problem?

Thank you so much for your help.

***edit :***
Just for updates, when on the computer B I do rostopic list I receive the list of topics that is running on the computer A, so the configuration is good.

However, I didn't try for the services, but on the computer B I can't receive the image coming from a kinect that is on the computer A.

Did anyone have this problem before?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9679/nodes-with-2-computers/) by [MorganCormier](https://answers.ros.org/users/360/morgancormier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2011-04-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aleeper](https://answers.ros.org/users/35/aleeper/) on 2011-04-08**:
your spacing/comma usage on the line with the ROS_MASTER_URIs is misleading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, did you try the following troubleshooting page - section 2?

[Troubleshooting - 2 Network Configuration](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Troubleshooting)

I think your problem comes from ROS_IP not being set correctly.

In my experience, **both** computers should have ROS_IP set to their own IP address.
Make sure they are set to the correct values as they are not initialized by default.

The one on which the master runs should have ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

The one that connect to the master should have ROS_MASTER_URI=http://[IP_OF_MASTER_MACHINE]:11311

Raph

---

Originally posted by [raphael favier](https://answers.ros.org/users/139/raphael-favier/) with karma: 1382 on 2011-04-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2015-03-18**:\

> In my experience, both computers should have ROS_IP set to their own IP address.

`ROS_IP` needs set on the terminals that run the nodes' processes.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you also need to tell computer A how to refer to itself,
e.g.   export ROS_HOSTNAME=192.168.1.100 on computer A.

---

Originally posted by [aleeper](https://answers.ros.org/users/35/aleeper/) with karma: 573 on 2011-04-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2011-04-11**:
I think, if you want to use an IP address, you should better use ROS_IP, not ROS_HOSTNAME.

**Comment by [MorganCormier](https://answers.ros.org/users/360/morgancormier/) on 2011-04-08**:
Thank you for the idea, I tried but It doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Relevant wiki pages that are very useful for everyone using multiple machines:

- [EnvironmentVariables](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/EnvironmentVariables) (in particular `ROS_MASTER_URI`, `ROS_HOSTNAME`, `ROS_IP`)
- [NetworkSetup](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/NetworkSetup)
- [MultipleMachines](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines)

---

Originally posted by [Patrick Bouffard](https://answers.ros.org/users/12/patrick-bouffard/) with karma: 2264 on 2011-04-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2